# How to modify ProgId of a Document Set in SharePoint 2013 using REST Api

Tags: web-services, sharepoint-addin

I have created a Document Set in a Document Library programmatically but it appears like a folder. I read that the ProgId property should be set to 'SharePoint.DocumentSet'. But I don't see the property returned by the item when making a rest call to get the item using the endpoint:

http://sharepointurl.com/wd/_api/Web/Lists(guid'556bf760-512e-46b6-9c95-0dabb41e456d')/Items(20)

How do I set this property using the Rest API? Is there a different name for this property when making REST call?

Thanks

Comment: When you say you created the Document Set "programmatically", what steps did you take, exactly?

Comment: Actually I created this inside a Workflow using Create Item Action and set the Content Type Id (to Document Set) and 'Path and Name' property to the Name I wanted to give to the Document Set. Later I have to call a webservice where I have to do some other work so I am thinking that I can fix this issue using REST API as I am already using it for other things inside the webservice.

Comment: That may be the source of the problem right there.  I'm not sure how exactly the OOB Create Item workflow action works, but I do know that in code there is a static `DocumentSet.Create()` method.  Someone I work with was creating Document Sets by creating folders and then changing the content type ID to that of the document set, and ended up with similar issues.  When he changed his code to use `DocumentSet.Create()` the doc sets were created correctly.  Maybe you can make a custom workflow action that leverages `DocumentSet.Create()`, and use that in your workflow instead of OOB Create Item?

Comment: Your diagnosis of the problem is correct. There is a way to fix the problem using CSOM but I m looking for an equivalent REST call. We are already using REST based calls and I don't want to start use CSOM for this one thing.